# Sensing range of load sensor

Tags: arduino, load, sensors

I need a sensor which can detect chair occupancy. By googling I found that potential solution for this issue could be load sensors. However, the specifications of the most of the load sensors that are available online suggest that a sensor can measure up to about 50kg (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10245).

Does this mean that I cannot detect when a person that weights over 50kg sits on the chair? Or this means that I just cannot measure accurately how much it weights?

I do not need information regarding the person weight.

Answer (score 0):

I have not interfaced with this sensor before, but as seen from the specifications of the product, 50kg is its maximum reading.

You can use other sensors with higher range
or you can use another type of sensors to detect the person which does not depend on the weight as simple IR detector or distance sensors such as ultrasonic.

Comment: But what makes you think that the force sensor from that link has a higher range. According to the specification, it can sense applied force in the range of 100g-10kg... It seems even worse.

Comment: Also, I am not sure that IR sensor is a good solution because I believe it can cause some fake alarms. Do you have some arguments for using the IR or ultrasonic sensor? Could they trigger event even when nobody is sitting, but just passing beside the chair?

Comment: I have edited the answer, i have read the range wrong,
 
Regarding the IR, in completely darkness it will cause fake alarms, it depends on where is your system mounted.

Using ultrasonic will not depend on ambient light, but it will consume more power as ultrasonic is an active sensor

Comment: There is simpler solution but i do no know if it can fit your application, you can use a limit switch, but the person sitting on the chair has to make a physical contact with switch.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you are trying to use a load sensor, it sounds more complicated, they could brake easily if constant use of 50kg or more on them. It may be easier with a ultrasonic sensor and simply detect the occupancy if somebody is close to the sensor, or even a motion sensor could work as well.

Comment: I do not think that motion sensor is a good option because it is too sensitive. I do not want to have event triggered when somebody walks near the chair.

Comment: I like the idea about the distance sensor, but if I put a pillow over the sensor that will not work. Am I right? I am looking for a solution that could be implemented on the chair.

Comment: it all depends where you locate the sensor and what type of chair is it. Can you assume that if there is  a pillow there is a person? can you  locate the sensor in the chair in front?